# How optimize the research of next free "slot" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, search, subquery

i've a problem and i can't find an easy solution.
I have self expanding stucture made in this way.

database1 | table1
          | table2
          ....
          | table n

.
.
.

databaseN | table 1
            table 2
            table n

each table has a structire like this:

id|value

each time a number is generated is put into the right database/table/structure (is divided in this way for scalability... would be impossible to manage table of billions of records in a fas way).

the problem that N is not fixed.... but is like a base for calculating numbers (to be precise N is known....62 but I can onlyuse a subset of "digits" that could be different in time).

for exemple I can work only with 0 1 and 2 and after a while (when I've done all the possibilities) I want to add 4 and so on (up to base 62).

I would like to find a simple way to find the 1st free slot to put the next randomly generated id but that could be reverted.

Exemple:

I have 0 1 2 3 as numbers I want use....

the element 2313 is put on dabase  2 table 3 and there will be 13|value into table.

the element 1301 is put on dabase  1 table 3 and there will be 01|value into table.

I would like to generate another number based on the next free slot.
I could test every slot starting from 0 to the biggest number but when there will be milions of records for every database and table this will be impossible.

the next element of the 1st exemple would be 2323(and not 2314 since I'm using only the 0 1 2 3 digits).
I would like som sort of invers code in mysql to give me the 23 slot on table 3 database 2 to transform it into the number. I could randomly generate a number and try to find the nearest free up and down but since the set is variable could not be a good choice.

I hope it will be clear enought to tell me any suggestion ;-)

Comment: I could also continue to generate  the random number and test if the slot is free....but if  the structure is about full I could take hours to find a free slot so is why I would like to generate the number starting from the free slot and not viceversa.

Comment: Using an index, a billion data sets work great. Maybe you do not want a relational database for your task.

Comment: "would be impossible to manage table of billions of records in a fas way".  This statement is false.  Tables with billions of rows can be handled by MySQL, using partitioning and indexing.

Comment: uhmm... I've calculated that every table will have 14776335 rows...

Comment: Considering the exemple I've done... I'll have....

(set 0 1 2) D=Database T=Table NN number *used slot

DTNN
0000 *
0001 *
0002 *
0010 *
0011
0012*
.
.
:
2222*

if I add another digit (3) the structure will be:

0000*
0001*
0002*
0003
0010*
0011
0012*
0013
.
.
2222*
:
3333*

and so on... I'd like to be returned in the 1st case 0011 and in the second one 0003. I could create the full data structure considering the table like an array..... with undef slots (for exemple in the 1st exemple the 03 into database 0 table 0 will be present but undef)... [cont]

Comment: but (the worst case) when I'll arrive to have only the 3332 free.... to find that position I have to scan all the prevoous 3 database and 3 table for all the elements... cinsider it for 14776335 each... also if you index them you need a lot of time....

Answer (score 0):

Use

- `show databases like 'database%'` and a loop to find non-existent databases
- `show tables like 'table%'` and a loop for tables
- `select count(*) from tableN` to see if a table is "full" or not.
- To find a free slot, walk the database with `count` in chunks.

This untested PHP/MySQL implementation will first fill up all existing databases and tables to base `N+1` before creating new tables or databases.
The `if(!$base)` part should be altered if another behaviour is wanted.

The `findFreeChunk` can also be solved with iteration; but I leave that effort to You.

```php
define (DB_PREFIX, 'database');
define (TABLE_PREFIX, 'table');
define (ID_LENGTH, 2)

function findFreeChunk($base, $db, $table, $prefix='')
{
    $maxRecordCount=base**(ID_LENGTH-strlen($prefix));
    for($i=-1; ++$i<$base;)
    {
        list($n) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(
            "select count(*) from `$db`.`$table` where `id` like '"
            . ($tmp = $prefix. base_convert($i, 10, 62))
            . "%'"));
        if($n<$maxRecordCount)
        {
            // incomplete chunk found: recursion
            for($k=-1;++$k<$base;)
                if($ret = findFreeChunk($base, $db, $table, $tmp)
                { return $ret; }
        }
    }
}

function findFreeSlot($base=NULL)
{
    // find current base if not given
    if (!$base)
    {
        for($base=1; !$ret = findFreeSlot(++$base););
        return $ret;
    }

    $maxRecordCount=$base**ID_LENGTH;

    // walk existing DBs
    $res = mysql_query("show databases like '". DB_PREFIX. "%'");
    $dbs = array ();
    while (list($db)=mysql_fetch_row($res))
    {
        // walk existing tables
        $res2 = mysql_query("show tables in `$db` like '". TABLE_PREFIX. "%'");
        $tables = array ();
        while (list($table)=mysql_fetch_row($res2))
        {
            list($n) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select count(*) from `$db`.`$table`"));
            if($n<$maxRecordCount) { return findFreeChunk($base, $db, $table); }
            $tables[] = $table;
        }
        // no table with empty slot found: all available table names used?
        if(count($tables)<$base)
        {
            for($i=-1;in_array($tmp=TABLE_PREFIX. base_convert(++$i,10,62),$tables););
            if($i<$base) return [$db, $tmp, 0];
        }
        $dbs[] = $db;
    }
    // no database with empty slot found: all available database names used?
    if(count($dbs)<$base)
    {
        for($i=-1;in_array($tmp=DB_PREFIX.base_convert(++$i,10,62),$dbs););
        if($i<$base) return [$tmp, TABLE_PREFIX. 0, 0];
    }
    // none: return false
    return false;
}
```

If you are not reusing your slots or not deleting anything, you can of course dump all this and simply remember the last ID to calculate the next one.